# Functor $G$ has right adjoint iff $Y \mapsto Hom(X, G(Y))$ is corepresentable

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors, representable-functor

My professor in his notes claims that a functor $G$ has a right adjoint iff the functor  $Y \mapsto Hom(X, G(Y)$ is corepresentable, i.e for each $X$ there is an object $F(X)$ and  a nutural by $X$ bijection

$Hom(F(X), Y) \cong Hom(X, G(Y))$.

Is that true? Of course, from corepresentability follows that $X \mapsto F(X)$ is indeed a functor (functoriality by $X$ plus Yoneda lemma gives us  a unique arrow $F \phi : F(X) \to F(X')$  for each $\phi: X \to X'$).But I don't see how do we get functoriality by Y.

If it was true it would be enough to check if two given functors is adjoint pair to verify functoriality just by one argument. I never heard of it and always checked both arguments.

Comment: Didn't you mean to write ``and a bijection $\hom(F(X),Y)\cong \hom(X,G(Y))$ natural in $Y$''?

Comment: I guess I did, but it makes everything even more confusing...

Comment: After that don't your observations show that there is a unique way to make $F$ into a functor such that the above becomes natural in $X$?

Comment: Not yet, but does it show that in general it is sufficient to check naturality in just one argument whenever I am checking if functors are adjoint?

Comment: Yes, because here the isomorphism is a huge constraint. As Nex pointed out, the isomorphism is natural in $Y$ by definition of corepresentability, and natural in $X$ by definition of $F$ as a functor (that is, its definition on maps). Now you just have to prove that if $F,G : C\times D\to E$ are functors and $\psi_{x,y} : F(x,y) \to G(x,y)$ is natural in $x$ and in $y$ (separately) then it is natural in $(x,y)$

Comment: Anyway, it is not true that you can check naturality just in one argument; there is a counterexample using both categories $B(Z/5Z)$ (the category with one object and a group as endomorphisms). But as the others point out, this is not the point, you have naturality separatedly in both arguments

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is true. It is proven, for instance, in Theorem IV.1.2(ii)/Corollary IV.2.2 of Mac Lane's [Categories for the Working Mathematician](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4757-4721-8). In fact, one does not even need $G$ to be a functor: see Theorem 2 of Street's [The core of adjoint functors](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/27/4/27-04abs.html).

However, note that this does *not* imply, when checking two functors are adjoint, that it is enough to check naturality in one of (or neither of) the arguments. The point of the theorem is that the action of $F$ on morphisms is uniquely determined by the hom set isomorphism, in such a way that the isomorphism is natural. If you start with a functor $F$ instead of just an assignment on objects, then you need to check naturality to ensure that the action of the functor $F$ on morphisms coincides with the canonical choice given by the hom-set isomorphism.

In other words, this theorem is useful when you want to construct an adjoint, rather than when you already have two functors and want to check that they are adjoint.